# What's the difference between the 'show' and the 'paint' events in SWT?

Tags: java, events, swt

The list of [SWT constants](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/SWT.html) in the SWT API supplies two very similar event types (for use with various event listeners):

1. [Show](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/SWT.html&anchor=Show)
2. [Paint](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/SWT.html#Paint)

What's the difference? Wouldn't all 'Show' events require a 'Paint' event and all 'Paint' events require a 'Show' event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=354574&seqNum=3) page:

Show:

> The widget is becoming visible

Paint:

> A control was asked to draw

---

So the main difference is the following:

`SWT.Show` is dispatched once the `Widget` becomes visible. `SWT.Paint` is called whenever the `Widget` changes state, i.e. when it has to be redrawn. For example when it is resized or the content changes.

To answer your last question. Every `Show` event is coupled with a `Paint`, but not every `Paint` is coupled with a `Show`.

---

To see how it works just attach two `Listener`s to a `Shell` that just print out `"Show"` or `"Paint"` and see when they are fired.